# A mystery table always there when update-database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am using asp.net core and entityframework. When I update the database the database gave error the InfoDay is already exisit. I delete the table, remove it from the dbContext. Check that no where else refter to the table but the table created despite all this. It is not in the migration file.

I started a project from scratch and create the dbcontext with no dbset. add-migration and nothing in it. update-database and ops...the table InfoDay is there with all columns from the other project.
Anyone has an idea of what is happning. I restart the computer, repeate but the same. I remove the entityframework and reinstall it in the project but still the same.
I took the project to another computer and run the project and did the same. It  works fine, No InfoDay table appears.
I unistall visual studio and reinstall it. I create another empty project after that with the same result.
How to correct this on my computer? Where this InfoDay hide itself?

Comment: When you call _update-database_ you specify a startup-project and a database project (if you don't specify it, it takes _something_). Depending on these, the update command picks maybe the _wrong project context_. Also maybe there are some artifacts which could be removed by calling "Clean solution".

Comment: any seed method?

Comment: No seed method. An empty project with empty dbcontext and the migration is empty but update-database on this computer will create InfoDay table. On the other computer no. I started the computer and repair visual studio community 2022 and updated it. No result

Comment: Notice it only happened on this computer. On the others no InfoDay table come up in the project when update-database

Comment: The first question is: where (in which project) do you use an `InfoDay` table or class? That should give a hint.

Comment: @Gert: I delete all project that have this class on my computer. But it is still the same. It is some how added to all update-database command.

Comment: I tried a new project with one model class temp in the context , the InfoDay table with all its columns from the old project are there. Although it is not there in the migration file.If I start again from the begininge and add a class with that name InfoDay with different columns the update refuse to add it because there is already because a table with the same name is already there.

Comment: I found something intresting. I open the sql data managment studio and create a database manually the InfoDay table will be there. It is in sql creation not in the visual studio or EF. Any body can help now?

Answer (score 0):

There is a template in sql that every created database follow,it is  model template. When reinstall sql it is still there because I didn,t delete the Data folder. When I unistall and delete these tempData and reinstall everythings worksed fine and this extra table disappear.